# Dependency error while trying to add another one in angular

Tags: angular, npm, dependencies

while trying to add new package this error message displaying. I dont know what is wrong  I have updated the angular and packages. How to fix this dependency broken error ?

```
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE could not resolve
npm ERR!
npm ERR! While resolving: @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap@12.1.1
npm ERR! Found: @angular/common@14.2.8
npm ERR! node_modules/@angular/common
npm ERR!   peer @angular/common@"^13.0.0 || ^14.0.0-0" from @angular/cdk@13.3.7
npm ERR!   node_modules/@angular/cdk
npm ERR!     peer @angular/cdk@"13.3.7" from @angular/material@13.3.7
npm ERR!     node_modules/@angular/material
npm ERR!       @angular/material@"^13.3.7" from the root project
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! See C:\Users\nizal\AppData\Local\npm-cache\eresolve-report.txt for a full report.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\nizal\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2022-12-21T09_02_27_026Z-debug-0.log
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you're trying to install the wrong version of `ng-bootstrap` (`12.x.x`) against the version of your angular project (`14.x.x`). As per the [official documentation](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/getting-started) for the package, you should be installing `ng-bootstrap@13.x.x`.

The package version `12.x.x` is trying to find the angular version it supports but is getting a different version, hence the error.

The two possible solutions are - either bumping the package version to `13.x.x` or downgrading your angular version in the project to `13.x.x`.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to run the npm install with `--legacy-peer-deps` command? It might be an issue with the peer dependencies in npm's latest version.

Comment: I have done that but it doesn't change anything

Comment: Hmm I see. I think Daksh's solution might help in that case!