# Facing issue npm ERR! peer @angular/common@"^12.0.0" from @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap@10.0.0

Tags: angular, typescript, npm, npm-install

Am facing this issue while deploying the angular application
Added the below package @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap. So please do the needfull the rootcause of the issue caused.

```
22-Dec-2022 07:03:47    npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
22-Dec-2022 07:03:47    **npm ERR! peer @angular/common@"^12.0.0" from @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap@10.0.0**
22-Dec-2022 07:03:47    npm ERR! node_modules/@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap
22-Dec-2022 07:03:47    npm ERR!   @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap@"^10.0.0" from the root project
22-Dec-2022 07:03:47    npm ERR! 
22-Dec-2022 07:03:47    npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
22-Dec-2022 07:03:47    npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
22-Dec-2022 07:03:47    npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
22-Dec-2022 07:03:47    npm ERR! 
22-Dec-2022 07:03:47    npm ERR! See /home/node/.npm/eresolve-report.txt for a full report.
22-Dec-2022 07:03:47    
22-Dec-2022 07:03:47    npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
22-Dec-2022 07:03:47    npm ERR!     /home/node/.npm/_logs/2022-12-22T12_03_44_868Z-debug-0.log
22-Dec-2022 07:03:47    The command '/bin/sh -c npm install  && npm cache clean --force' returned a non-zero code:
```

My angular version is

```
    / \   _ __   __ _ _   _| | __ _ _ __     / ___| |   |_ _|
   / △ \ | '_ \ / _` | | | | |/ _` | '__|   | |   | |    | |
  / ___ \| | | | (_| | |_| | | (_| | |      | |___| |___ | |
 /_/   \_\_| |_|\__, |\__,_|_|\__,_|_|       \____|_____|___|
                |___/
    

    Angular CLI: 13.3.4
    Node: 16.15.0
    Package Manager: npm 8.16.0
    OS: win32 x64
    
    Angular: 13.3.5
    ... animations, cdk, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
    ... language-service, localize, material, platform-browser
    ... platform-browser-dynamic, router
    
    Package                         Version
    ---------------------------------------------------------
    @angular-devkit/architect       0.1303.4
    @angular-devkit/build-angular   13.3.4
    @angular-devkit/core            13.3.4
    @angular-devkit/schematics      13.3.4
    @angular/cli                    13.3.4
    @angular/http                   7.2.16
    @schematics/angular             13.3.4
    rxjs                            6.6.7
    typescript                      4.6.4
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please take a look here, as this might help you resolve your issue. Looks like the same problem: [Dependency error while trying to add another one in angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74873614/dependency-error-while-trying-to-add-another-one-in-angular/74873705#74873705)

Comment: issue fixed, upgrading the version of ng-bootstrap 11.0.0. Thank you for your helps